# Cast ArrayList after passing through method argument

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists, one is `ArrayList<A>` and the other `ArrayList<B>`.
I have a method that is around 95% the same for both, so I would like to use it in both cases, without having to write two different methods for different arguments.

Could I use something like the following?

```
public void method( ArrayList<?> list){
    if( getListClass == A )
         cast list to ArrayList<A>;
    else
         cast list to ArrayList<B>;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics are a compile time feature.  This means casting at runtime doesn't mean any thing.  I suggest you treat the `List<CommonAB>` where `CommonAB` is the interface which is common to A and B.

What you can do is

```
updateListA(List<A> list) {
    commonCode(list);
    specificCodeForA(list);
}

updateListB(List<B> list) {
    commonCode(list);
    specificCodeForB(list);
}
```

Note: you cannot get the type of the generic in the list as the type is an `ArrayList` at runtime, not `ArrayList<A>` or `ArrayList<B>`

Comment: Aren't lists invariant (Edit: in their generic parameter) in Java? This would mean that you can't pass a `List<A>` into a method that expects `List<CommonAB>`.

Comment: I thought about it, but although the calculations are the same (the 95% similarity) the results are to be write to fields that are not common to both structures.

Comment: @AmiguelS Then the solution is probably to split the method into three methods: One for the common part and one method each for the specifics of `A` and `B`. Consider updating your question with the implementation of `method` to show the differences and similarities.

Comment: If there are fields not common to both structures, then the two structures are not simply Arraylist<A> and ArrayList<B>